# How do I make a horizontal list of inline elements stack vertically when the div container is resized?

Tags: html, css, layout

My problem (note the yellow tiles and how they "overflow"):

*(link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6yDM.jpg) as I don't have enough reputation points.*

The screenshot above shows how the little tiles (yellowish rectangles) disregard the boundaries of the grey box.

I want the tiles to behave similar to how I have simulated in the screenshot below:

*(link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBhyJ.jpg) as I don't have enough reputation points.*

So basically, I want the tiles (which are dynamically generated in JavaScript) to automatically respect the boundaries of their parent container and shift down to another row instead of overflowing.

The tiles are coded as such:

```
<span class='tile'>Tile content</span>
```

...and are dynamically generated using JavaScript.
The tiles are place within a `div`:

```
<div id="conversionPanel" class="panel">
       <span class='tile'>Tile1</span>
       <span class='tile'>Tile2</span>
       <!-- etc. The number of tiles are variable -->
</div>
```

And the conversionPanel CSS is nothing special: `margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;`

The CSS I'm using for the tiles are:

```
.tile {
   display:inline;
   padding:5px;
   margin:3px;
   border:1px solid white;
   /* The rest is just lots of css3 visual stuff */
 }
```

Can anybody help me with this? I've searched everywhere but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: are you sure of the elements that are being generated by javascript and of your CSS? `span`s like the ones you describe should simply wrap in a `div` like the one you describe and a simple `text-align: center` should do the trick, but overflowing like that probably means there's some element or CSS property you've missed

Comment: @madd0: Yes, I triple checked that JavaScript was generating the 'span's correctly. Also, the CSS is working, because the tiles are already formatted with gradients, drop shadows, etc. when I test my code in a browser.
Also, I'm using the 'span' element instead of the 'div' element because it doesn't do any formatting on its own (unlike the 'div' element, which includes a paragraph break).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. The code below treats each tile like a word in a wrapped line of text.

```
   .panel {
     text-align: center;
     width: 300px;
   }
   .tile {
     display:inline-block;
     padding:5px;
     margin:3px;
     border:1px solid white;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked PERFECTLY.
So simple, yet so elegant! :D